# In uml-model set instance of java class as parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, papyrus, uml-designer

In an UML Model i would like to give an instance of a JAVA-class as parameter to a method.
example :

```
public void setDate(LocalDate date){...}
```

i don´t find a way to achieve this either with Papyrus or with Eclipse/UMLDesigner.

I cannot set LocalDate as Type of parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, you need to create a class LocalDate manually in your UML model. 
In the next release 8.0 of UML Designer, a new feature will allow you to create the UML model from Java code. To be sure that your use case is well handled, please add a new issue on the UML Designer bug tracker: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/new